# Grails - join association twice in Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, grails

Is possible to join an association twice in Criteria?

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria();
def results = criteria.list() {
    childObject1{
      eq("childObjProp","childObjProp1") 
      childObject2 {
          eq("testId", 1 as long) //User input
      }

    }
    childObject1{
      eq("childObjProp","childObjProp1_1") 
      childObject2 {
          eq("testId", 1 as long) //User input
      }

    }
}
```

Where `childObject2`'s data is `user input`, it may available or it may not 
available. I having an `SQL` solution. But I need `criteria solution`

This question is more related to this [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879)